# Preg_replace PHP заменить значения в URL

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка URL, например: `blog/?filter=1&check=1&color=Белый,Красный&size=170`

Код:

```
$url = preg_replace('/=(.*?)($|&)/i', "={\1}&", $url);
```

Результат: `blog/?filter={1}&check={1}&color={Белый,Красный}&size={170}&`

Необходимо: `blog/?filter=1&check={check}&color={color}&size={size}`

Я новичок в регулярках, подскажите правильный вариант пожалуйста.

Comment: А по каким причинам нельзя использовать [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) совместно с [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)? Имею ввиду, что получить строку запроса (после символа вопроса) можно с помощью parse_url, а распарсить на ключ-значение с помощью parse_str...

Comment: @XelaNimed можно и так, я думал, что preg_match будет оптимизированей чем куча функций. Или тут не велика потеря?

Comment: Не могу привести точные данные бенчмарка для сравнения этих двух разных подходов, но в общем для парсинга строк лучше избегать использования регулярных выражений. Тем более для Вашего случая уже есть стандартные методы, которые будет удобней читать, сопровождать и выполнять отладку. Помимо этого Вы сможете использовать маппинг между переменными запроса и значениями для замены.

Comment: Не надо использовать регулярки там, где есть более понятные функции.

Comment: @XelaNimed спасибо, так и сделал)